# Hibernate configuration issue upgrading grails version from 1.3.8 to 2.0.4

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm trying to upgrade a grails application from version from 1.3.8 to 2.0.4

After taking care of compilation errors to handle changed libraries etc - I get it to where it tries to start up - however it gets to where it tries to configure hibernate and than hangs.
Here's the portion of the log from 1.3.8:

> 2012-09-04 16:27:33,806 [main] INFO  hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean  - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
>   2012-09-04 16:27:33,941 [main] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/Users/userX/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-1.7.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
>   2012-09-04 16:27:34,718 [main] WARN  hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [common.SecRole]; using defaults.
>   2012-09-04 16:27:45,504 [main] WARN  hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
>   2012-09-04 16:27:45,505 [main] WARN  hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.

And from the non-working portion in 2.0.4:

> 2012-09-04 17:16:49,488 [pool-4-thread-1] INFO  hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean  - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
>   2012-09-04 17:16:49,619 [pool-4-thread-1] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/Users/userX/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
>   2012-09-04 17:16:51,175 [pool-4-thread-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [common.SecRole]; using defaults.

Any ideas what I'm missing?  It just seems to be hanging on configuring the cache for Hibernate.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you upgrading the Hibernate plugin also?

Comment: Yes the hibernate plugin is upgraded from 1.3.7 to 2.0.4

Comment: Ok, figured it out (eventually): One of the domain objects has an index, and grails was regenerating the index.  Since the table was pretty large (30G) it was taking a very long time to generate and looked like it was just sitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the domain objects had an index in the static mapping and it was getting regenerated in the database.  Since the table was large, regenerating the index took a very long time - during which the application appeared to just be hanging.